# How do I return the cell address of every instance of a key in a 1D array?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I’m trying to find every instance of a name in a list of names, and compile their locations in a list. I already know TEXTJOIN can do this with comma delineation, but I can’t figure out how to implement it.

I’ve tried using FIND, SEARCH, and MATCH in various ways, but can’t get it to work.

Here’s a mockup, where the filled in section is the goal.
[image: Click here]
This is the formula I’m trying to use:
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(E2:E, QUERY(L:O, "select L,sum(O) where L is not null group by L label sum(O)''"), 2))

Update:
And here’s an actual graph photo. [image: Click here]

For reference, Base Stakes and Results work perfectly, the only issue being that they are referring to the ELO column(the one for which the desired result is filled in), which is broken. How should I translate the working formula to function without detecting circular logic?

Comment: Use `FILTER()` then `TEXTJOIN()`. Share a sample workbook so that we can suggest exact formula.

Comment: @Harun24hr It has been added, but I can change it if anything is unclear or if something I did not include becomes apparently necessary.

Comment: You are trying to get a total by name?

Comment: @BlindSpots Sorry, I fell asleep—what exactly do you mean? In terms of my goal, I want to find every instance of a cell in A1 in the Matchups column, find their corresponding values in the gain column, and sum those, finally placing them in the Score column at the same level as their corresponding names.

Comment: Okay, I added [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75272184/)  that and does also generates the list of names based on the matchups column.    Can you advise what additional logic you are struggling with and I can add that.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=QUERY(D:F; "select D,sum(F) where D is not null group by D label sum(F)''")
```

if you insist on injection use:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A; QUERY(D:F; 
 "select D,sum(F) where D is not null group by D label sum(F)''"); 2; )))
```

---

### update:

use in F2:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(E2:E, QUERY({L:L, O:O}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label sum(Col2)''"), 2, )))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I’m getting a circular dependency error when I try to use it on my sheet. It works fine on the sample, but for some reason it’s apparently in a circular dependency. I’ll update it with a photo of my actual sheet, and the formula I’m trying to use. Thank you!

Comment: should i send it to you or did you just mean that I should add it to the post?

Comment: Do you see it in the post? If you dont I’ll try to put it in comments

Comment: I’ll add the link to a copy

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18pMHbFPwmb_s8iv0S8YK-JFlyuHxtSoqDEex_MKh-ak/edit

Comment: permission updated

Comment: Sorry I updated the original, try again and you’ll probably get in

Comment: thank you so much! Would I be able to add 500 to each value as a baseline?

Comment: @FishInaTree0 `=INDEX(IFNA(500+VLOOKUP(E2:E, QUERY({L:L, O:O}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label sum(Col2)''"), 2, )))`

Answer (score 0):

##### Formula in Table 1 `$A$2`

```
=MAP(SORT(UNIQUE(D2:D)), 
     LAMBDA(n, IF(n<>"",
           {n,SUM(INDEX(FILTER(D:F,D:D=n),,3))},"")))
```

[image]